# C++ observer pattern via boost.signals2

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I was looking for a thread safe implementation of the observer pattern. I read https://xinhuang.github.io/posts/2015-02-11-how-a-multi-threaded-implementation-of-the-observer-pattern-can-fail.html and was thinking about point 4 "Don't reinvent the wheel, use Boost.Signals2 instead". So I tried the following code and wanted to  ask if it is safe to be used in a multithreaded application? What happens if an `Observer` is destructed during `notifyObservers`?

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class AbstractObserver {
public:
    using SignalType = boost::signals2::signal<void()>;

    virtual ~AbstractObserver() = default;

    virtual void notify() = 0;

    void registerAtSubject(SignalType &sig)
    {
        connection_ = sig.connect([this]() { notify(); });
    }

private:
    boost::signals2::scoped_connection connection_;
};

class Subject {
    AbstractObserver::SignalType sig_;
public:
    void registerObserver(AbstractObserver &observer)
    {
        observer.registerAtSubject(sig_);
    }

    void notifyObservers() const
    {
        sig_();
    }
};

class Observer : public AbstractObserver {
    std::string id_;
public:
    explicit Observer(std::string id) : id_(std::move(id))
    {};

    void notify() override
    {
        std::cout << "Observer " << id_ << " got notified" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Subject c;
    {
        Observer o2("B");
        {
            Observer o1("A");
            c.registerObserver(o1);
            c.notifyObservers();
            c.registerObserver(o2);
            c.notifyObservers();
        }
        c.notifyObservers();
    }
    c.notifyObservers();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost.Signals2 is a thread-safe library. It uses mutex locking internally. There are some caveats, as explained in [this article](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.signals2-multithreading):

> Almost all classes provided by Boost.Signals2 are thread safe and can
>   be used in multithreaded applications. For example, objects of type
>   `boost::signals2::signal` and `boost::signals2::connection` can be
>   accessed from different threads.
>
> On the other hand, `boost::signals2::shared_connection_block` is not
>   thread safe. This limitation is not important because multiple objects
>   of type `boost::signals2::shared_connection_block` can be created in
>   different threads and can use the same connection object.

but in its simplest and default forms, Boost.Signals2 is multi-threading safe.

Your given example is, indeed, thread-safe.

> What happens if an Observer is destructed during notifyObservers?

The slot is disconnected preemptively.